# Using the BFGS method to find roots of few equations

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use the BFGS method to find the roots of these equations.

1. a*x[0]^2 - b*x[1]^2

```
a = 35; b = 25; d = 15
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def f(x):
    return a*x[0]^2 - b*x[1]^2

optimize.fmin_bfgs(f,[0.55,0.65])
```

The output I am getting is,

```
Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
         Current function value: -2791745.308471
         Iterations: 3
         Function evaluations: 196
         Gradient evaluations: 46

array([ 300.41455833, 2439.35586751])
```

The output is of course not desirable. I want to add two more equations and want the roots x[0], x[1], x[2]. Is it possible in BFGS, if so, how?
The two more equations are like,

1. b*x[2]^2 - x[1]^2 == 0
2. d *x[0]*x[2]*(x[2] + x[0]) - x[1]^2 == 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BFGS algorithm tries to find a local minimum of the given function, as the method name `fmin_bfgs` indicates. You can use [`scipy.optimize.root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html) to find the root of the function `F: R^n -> R^n` of `n` variables:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root

a = 35; b = 25; d = 15

def F(x):
    return np.array([a*x[0]**2 - b*x[1]**2, 0])

# res.x contains your root
res = root(F, x0=np.ones(2))
```

In order to solve `a*x[0]**2 - b*x[1]**2 == 0` we added the equation `0 == 0`, since `root` expects 2 equations for a function of 2 variables. When adding your two other equations, we have a function of three variables, i.e:

```py
def F(x):
    eq1 = a*x[0]**2 - b*x[1]**2
    eq2 = b*x[1]**2 - x[0]**2
    eq3 = d*x[0]*x[2]*(x[2] + x[0]) - x[1]**2
    return np.array([eq1, eq2, eq3])

# res.x contains your root
res = root(F, x0=np.ones(3))
```

Note also that in Python, the `^` operator denotes the bitwise XOR. Use `x[0]**2` to denote the power of two of `x[0]`.

Comment: Thank You @joni.
I got the point of ^ and ***. 
One thing I could not understand, Instead of giving 0==0, can I utilize another (or more than one) equation that I have put, like
b*x[2]**2 - x[1]**2 

                         or                      

d *x[0]x[2](x[2] + x[0]) - x[1]**2

Comment: @PrasantaBandyopadhyay Sure. In case you only want to solve the first equation, we include `0 == 0` since it is always fulfilled. You are free to add more equations as long as the function `F` is a function of `n` variables and returns a vector of shape `(n,)`. Btw, I edited my answer.